# What is the difference between Synchronous and asynchronous I2C in embedded programming?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, i2c

What is the difference between Synchronous and asynchronous I2C in embedded programming? Could anyone explain this using an example? When to use either of them?

Comment: Please provide more details and context on your question.

Answer (score 1):

I2C is a synchronous protocol, meaning that the communicating parties do not need to agree to a certain speed beforehand - think at the asynchronous serial lines like RS-232, where no communication can succeed if the parties don't use the same baud rate.

The sync/async someone refers to, speaking of i2c, it's in another level, we may call it API. A synchronous API (or routine) will start the communication and will *not* return control to the program until the whole data will be sent or received. The time taken to do the transfer will be unavailable for the program.

If the communication is asynchronous, the calling program can invoke the i2c driver and then continue to do its work. Later, the program should be notified (or the program should check) about the result of the transaction: "is the writing/reading still in progress?"; and if it is terminated, did it go well or not?

Sync/async in the context of i2c can be thought the same as disk (file) I/O: often synchronous disk access is used, which is simple and effective: read some data in memory, check if the reading was ok, do something with the data, and go ahead. In the asynchronous way, the program says something like "I need those data: I/O driver, please fetch them while I do something else; when the data will be available I will do something with that".

The asynchronous mode for i2c can be pleasant especially because i2c is slow when compared to other ways to exchange data. On the other hand, i2c is used for little data, certainly not for a hard disk!

Speaking strictly about the embedded world, often the MCU has to do many things concurrently, and an i2c device can be simply slow enough to make the MCU lose too much time if the i2c is bit-banged. But often there is hardware support, interrupt-driven. Anyway, a non-blocking (i.e. asynchronous) API is more difficult to manage.

-- UPDATE AFTER COMMENT --

> "often there is hardware support, interrupt-driven. Anyway, a non-blocking (i.e. asynchronous) API is more difficult to manage" Do you mean the implementation of synchronus I2C in a multimodal sensor system can be easier than the other and still give similar performance.

Let's assume there is an asynchronous hardware+driver support: we call

i2c_write(periph_addr, data_to_send[], 6);
// send 6 bytes to the peripheral

After few microseconds the routine returns, but the communication is still ongoing. At this point we can not issue another i2c_write(...), because we would interrupt the ongoing one. The program could do something else, yes, but *not* use the same bus. And if instead i2c_write(...) we used a

i2c_read(...);

we would have not the data ready when the routine returns: the program must use i2c_read(), but use the data only later, when arrived, and *without* touching the i2c bus in the meanwhile. Not difficult to do, but surely a synchronous call/API like:

if ( i2c_read(some_data) == I2COK)
display(some_data);
else display(error);

is far simpler.

Comment: Actually I²C is more complicated than that and an agreement is happening, although transparently to the user.

Comment: @0andriy yes, there is much more to the i2c protocol; I thought it was better not to go too deep, until the OP had more doubts.

Comment: Thank you @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica for this great explanation, I am new to the firmware development and I found this helpful to understand more.
I would like to understand more on these lines "often there is hardware support, interrupt-driven. Anyway, a non-blocking (i.e. asynchronous) API is more difficult to manage"

Do you mean the implementation of synchronus I2C in a multimodal sensor system can be easier than the other and still give similar performance.  
Also by saying that asynchronous API is more difficult to manage, what sort of challenges you would expect from that?

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me,

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica,    For a multimodal sensor project which requires precise timing, it's better to take the complex path and develop the async i2c. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: @saba007 what you say may be true; to evaluate, one should know what hardware and requirements you have in mind. Surely the "complex path" can do anything the "simple path" does, it is only more difficult. But in both ways, you can not take more throughput or more "time precision" from an i2c bus. Different is if there are more buses.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica in my system there are UART and SPI buses which are clocking at a higher rate. So I hope the async approach would reduce the risk of slowing down other buses.